# How to load plist email address in email send

Tags: iphone, xcode, email, plist

I set up a plist and the plist have lots of email address, then I want to load email address from plist and send the email.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.plist"];
NSArray *emailNames = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:docPath];
```

TO send your email:

```
NSString *emailTitle = @"Email Title";
NSString *messageBody = @"This is where the body goes";
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithArray:emailNames];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

// Present mail view controller on screen
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```